# ボタンクリックでコンソール上にメッセージを表示させたい

Tags: javascript, html

ボタンをクリックするたびにコンソール上にonとoffを交互に表示させるプログラムを作りたいのですが、ボタンを押しても動作しません。ページを読み込んだ段階でコンソール上に"Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener is not a function at a.js:11"と表示されます。

そこでjsファイルの11行目を"btn.onclick = change;"と書き換えてonclickを使う方法も試したのですが、この場合はコンソール上にエラーメッセージは表示されなくなりましたが、ボタンを押しても何も動作しませんでした。

addEventListnerおよびonclickが機能しない原因を教えていただきたいです。

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("off");

const change = function () {
    if (btn.className == "off") {
        console.log("off");
    } else if (btn.className == "on") {
        console.log("on");
    }
};
btn.addEventListener("click", change);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Events: Task 1</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="preview"></section>

        <button class="off">button</button>
    </body>
    <script></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

あなたのコードでは`btn`がHTMLのbutton要素ではなく、要素を1個だけ持つ`HTMLCollection`(DOM操作における配列のようなもの)になるからです。メソッド名が`getElementsByClassName`の形で、複数形の`Elements`になっている点に注意してください。

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

button要素を取り出したければ、`getElementsByClassName`の結果から1つを取り出してください。

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("off")[0]; //<-

const change = function () {
    if (btn.className == "off") {
        console.log("off");
    } else if (btn.className == "on") {
        console.log("on");
    }
};
btn.addEventListener("click", change);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Events: Task 1</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="preview"></section>

        <button class="off">button</button>
    </body>
    <script></script>
</html>
```

なお、「onとoffを交互に」にの部分は、まだ完全には実装されていなかったようなので、そのままにしてあります。`addEventListener`が動作するようになれば、ご自身で解決できるだろうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

複数クラス名が"off"の要素がある場合のコードの例です。

```
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("off");
btns = Array.from(btns)

const change = function(btn) {
    if (btn.className == "off") {
        console.log("off");
    } else if (btn.className == "on") {
        console.log("on");
    }
};

btns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", change(btn));
});
```